# Why are the last 2 expressions in the following diagram are equal?

Tags: combinatorics, tensor-products

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

(Divided powers) Consider the vector space $C = k[t]$ of polynomials in one variable. Prove that there exists a unique coalgebra structure $(C, \Delta, \varepsilon)$ on $C$ such that $$\Delta(t^n) = \sum_{p + q = n} t^p \otimes t^q \text{ and } \varepsilon(t^n) = \delta_{n0}$$ for all $n \geq 0.$

**Here is my trial to prove coassociativity:**

> [image]

I am wondering why the last expressions on the left and the right should be equal, could someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n$. We have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{\substack{p,q\ge 0\\p+q=n}}
\sum_{\substack{k,l\ge 0\\k+l=p}}
t^k\otimes t^l\otimes t^q
&=
\sum_{\substack{q,k,l\ge 0\\k+l+q=n}}t^k\otimes t^l\otimes t^q\ ,
\\
\sum_{\substack{p,q\ge 0\\p+q=n}}
\sum_{\substack{r,s\ge 0\\r+s=q}}
t^p\otimes t^r\otimes t^s
&=
\sum_{\substack{p,r,s\ge 0\\p+r+s=n}}t^p\otimes t^r\otimes t^s\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and there is an obvious bijection for the index sets under the sum bringing $(k,l,q)$ to $(p,r,s)$.